# Could mmap generate huge writing on nagios rrd files?

Tags: mmap, nagios

Checking a storage usage issue I have found that [nagios](https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/nagioscore/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mmap&type=) generate a huge amount of file writing. Following the issue I  made a check about the system calls on centOS 6.8 by strace

```
#strace -f -p $nagiosServicePID

[pid 32544] open("/opt/nagios/pnp/var/perfdata/sw-int02/If_GigabitEthernet1_0_29.rrd", O_RDWR) = 5
[pid 32544] fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4217672, ...}) = 0
[pid 32544] fadvise64(5, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_RANDOM) = 0
[pid 32544] mmap(NULL, 4217672, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, 5, 0) = 0x7f252fc3c000
[pid 32544] madvise(0x7f252fc3c000, 4217672, MADV_RANDOM) = 0
[pid 32544] madvise(0x7f252fc3c000, 128, MADV_WILLNEED) = 0
[pid 32544] madvise(0x7f252fc3c000, 1320, MADV_WILLNEED) = 0
[pid 32544] madvise(0x7f252fc3c000, 1440, MADV_WILLNEED) = 0
[pid 32544] madvise(0x7f252fc3c000, 16, MADV_WILLNEED) = 0
[pid 32544] fcntl(5, F_SETLK, {type=F_WRLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
[pid 32544] msync(0x7f252fc3c000, 4217672, MS_ASYNC) = 0
[pid 32544] munmap(0x7f252fc3c000, 4217672) = 0
[pid 32544] close(5)                    = 0
```

It suggest me that nagios open the rrd file, write onto the memory map and sync back that memory map to the disk.
I am affraid about that even the rrd file is modified in 4 bytes, the complete rrd file is rewritten to the disk. It simple kills the expensive SSDs.

Could it be the reason of this huge disk writing ?

Is it possible to decrease the disk writing some way with nagios ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using PNP it looks like, which means the actual file that writes the RRD file is in `process_perfdata.pl`, not Nagios itself. The function that is doing the writing is called `data2rrd`. What you're asking is essentially a limitation of RRDtool.

If this writing seems expensive to you, you may want to look at setting up RRDcached. RRDcached will log all of the writes that need to occur towards RRD files in a specific directory, and then at a specified interval update them all at the same time.

You can also make sure you have enough buffer cache so that all of your RRD file blocks are essentially updated in memory, and changes to disk are less sporadic. You can do this by ensuring you have adequate memory available to the machine.

Also, you can tune your RRD files (or PNP4Nagios - we'll get to that in a second) to store less information so that their overall size is a bit smaller. The trade-off here is that you'll end up with less historical performance data. This may or may not be an issue for you.

You can tune PNP by looking at `/usr/local/nagios/etc/pnp/rra.cfg` and `/usr/local/nagios/etc/pnp/process_perfdata.cfg`. That is where those files are located on my system, your mileage may vary.

Finally: make sure your system is using the latest version of RRDtool. If you installed via `yum` or `apt` it may be a bit out of date. I highly recommend compiling from source, as a lot of performance improvements and bug fixes have found their ways in throughout the years.

You can find more information about RRDtool here: http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/index.en.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. As I can see, it is possible to compile rrdtool with mmap or with the old fseek method. I can also test it myself or ask my question on mmap more specifically.